# no enclosing instance of type is accessible, error in my code

Tags: java, class

I get the following error

> no enclosing instance of type is accessible

when I try to add this line:

```
Receiver.this.getMyField()
```

which tries to get a value from another class called `receiver`.

```
  private void initSenderAndReceiver(final Socket clientSocket) {

    Receiver receiver = new Receiver(clientSocket, chatView);
    final Sender sender = new Sender(clientSocket, chatView);

    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sender.sendMessage(chatBox.getText());
            //sender.sendMessage(Receiver.this.Clientcoordinate1,Receiver.this.Clientcoordinate2);
            //sender.sendMessage();
            Receiver.this.getMyField();
            chatBox.setText(""); //Clear the chat box
        }
    });

    Thread receiverThread = new Thread(receiver);
    receiverThread.run();
}
```

Comment: Why not declare `receiver` final and access it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `receiver.getMyField();` declaring it `final` as done for `sender` object.

Comment: but could someone explain to me what was the problem which led to this error.

Comment: When you create an instance of an **anonymous inner class**, any variables which are used within that class have their values copied in via the _autogenerated constructor_ (you cannot declare constructors in an anonymous class). This avoids the compiler having to autogenerate various extra types to hold the logical state of the "local variables".

Comment: As the value has been copied into the instance of the anonymous inner class, it would look odd if the variable could be modified by the rest of the method - you could have code which appeared to be working with an out-of-date variable (because that's effectively what would be happening... you'd be working with a copy taken at a different time). Likewise if you could make changes within the anonymous inner class, developers might expect those changes to be visible within the body of the enclosing method.

Comment: Making the variable final removes all these possibilities - as the value can't be changed at all, you don't need to worry about whether such changes will be visible.